# NullReferenceException when assigning RegistryKey

Tags: c#, registry, variable-assignment

I am trying to over hand a RegistryKey to a class in my dll. Reading the Key into an temporary Key works(checked in debugger), but a NullReferenceException gets thrown when i try to assign it to the target RegistryKey-variable in that static class.

The following code is executed in the Constructor of the MainWindow (WPF-application)

```
try {
    RegistryKey tK;
    tK = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Software Untergrund");
    Options.SU = tK; //<= NullRefenceException gets thrown here
} catch (NullReferenceException e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    throw;
}
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: So is `Options` null? Is there special code attached to `SU` if it's a property?

Comment: `RegistryKey tk = Registry.ClassesRoot;` try adding this inplace of `RegistryKey = tk`
then possibly doing something like this 
`RegistryKey subKey = key.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Software Untergrund");`

Comment: @gunr2171: Options is a class that contains different properties like paths to specific folders etc. SU is a RegistryKey with the getter-method:
    RegistryKey SU {get; set;}

Comment: @DJKRAZE: the tK = ... line works, tK has content (subkeys etc.) when i try to assign it to Options.SU